# php script returns every row containing a word

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search

This php script returns every row in the mySQL database:

```
<?php

$host = "host_name";
$db = "database_name"; 
$user = "user_name";
$pass = "password";

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM farmer";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);
    }


}
```

?>

This script works well but returns every row.

Let's say my database contains the names of farmers and their types of produce.  The first column is "id, the second is "farmer_name", and the third is "produce".  The produce is entered like this:  beans, corn, lettuce, strawberries, tomatoes.

What I want to do is change the above script so that it returns only the rows containing the names of farmers who grow corn, and all the types of produce they grow.  So, I don't just want the name, but also the list of all products, so long as the farmer grows corn.

Is this possible based on the way the database is structured?  I made several attempts using needle/haystack but came up empty handed.  I know very little about php.

Comment: first off if you have the ability to design the structure of the tables, don't do it this way, as it is de-normalized

Comment: Just to clarify, does the product column contain a single item per row, or is it a string containing all of the produce?

Comment: the latter would be awful !

Comment: It contains a string.  The only other way I could think of structuring it would to be to add a column for each.  Would that be the best practice?

Comment: absolutely not. look into 1NF, 2NF, 3NF and E.F. Codd. Should i write it for you, i would be happy to

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It's all new territory for me.  I did a Google search on what you suggested and it looks like there's much to read.  I'll figure it out.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `farmer_name`, `produce` FROM `farmer` WHERE `produce` LIKE '%corn%'
```

This will return the rows where corn is found anywhere in the produce field.

Comment: oh yikes this means you have them all glommed together in one column. if they decide to grown eggplants, you can't add a row but have to parse. database tables aren't designed this way

Comment: It appeared that that was your choice. With your current structure your ADD query would be "UPDATE `farmer` SET `produce` = CONCAT(`produce` , ', eggplant') WHERE `farmer_name`=$farmerName";

Answer (score 0):

it is as simple as using WHERE

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM farmer WHERE produce = 'corn'";
```

please note that `mysql_` functions were depriciated

Comment: I like simple.  But, the above returns only [].